# How do I duplicate the content of a list in swift

Tags: swift

I can't seem to find the answer to this question (I keep getting answers for multiplying a list). I'm new to swift so bear with me.

I have a list say

```
a = ['a']
```

in python I can just do `a*3` and then I end up with `['a','a','a']` however swift doesn't seem to like this. What is the correct syntax to get the same result in swift?

Note: Suppose that `a` always has a length of 1.

Comment: It might be helpful to formally define what you expect to happen when you multiply an array by anything.

Comment: In this example, you want to convert an array with a single item into an array with multiple items of the same value?

Comment: What if there are two elements in the list? What should happen then?

Comment: @bsod, yes that's what I'm hoping to achieve

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't multiply an array by an `Int` in Swift, but that isn't hard to add:

```
func *<T>(_ array: [T], _ count: Int) -> [T] {
    return Array(Array(repeating: array, count: count).joined())
}
```

**Examples:**

```
let a = ["a", "b"]
let a3 = a * 3
print(a3)
```

> ```
> ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]
> ```

```
print(["b"] * 5)
```

> ```
> ["b", "b", "b", "b", "b"]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For people who also have a similar problem, credit goes to matt for finding the solution. Below is the example in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init).

```
let fiveZs = Array(repeating: "Z", count: 5)
print(fiveZs)
// Prints "["Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"]"
```